# ¿como unir 2 atributos en una tabla?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

tengo una tabla llamada responsables con 3 atributos(id,nombre,apellido).
Quiero que las entidades nombre y apellido se unan en una nueva entidad(usuarios).
y que al final quede la tabla responsables con 2 atributos(id,usuarios).
utilizo php my admin.

Comment: Puedes agregar que llevas hecho? así como la estructura de las tablas, aclarando que tu usas seguro MariaDB o MySQL, pues PHPMyAdmin es solo una interfaz visual para manipular tus bases de datos

Comment: utilizo el que viene con xampp. y la tabla se llama responsables.tengo 3 atributos: id(int),nombre(text),apellido(text)                                                                           ----------------------------------------------------
|   id               |   Nombre    |   apellido  |
----------------------------------------------------
|    334           |   juan          |  Perez      |                                                     necesito que los atributos nombre y apellido se "unan" en uno nuevo(usuario)

Comment: ojala se entienda lo que intente explicar, se explicaría mejor con imágenes pero esta pagina no me deja subir imagenes

Comment: dale editar y añade la estructura de las tablas como código, después seleccionalo y presiona `ctrl + k` de modo que quedará formateado, salvo en casos excepcionales las imágenes no son estrictamente necesarias

Comment: sinceramente me perdí en estructuras de tablas como codigo(no lo encontre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Crear columna:**

```
ALTER TABLE responsables ADD COLUMN usuarios varchar(150)
```

**Asignar valores:**

Utiliza la función `CONCAT(expresion1,expresion2,expresion3)`

```
UPDATE responsables SET usuarios=CONCAT(nombre," ", apellido)
```

**Edición:** Pensaba que decías una selección y no modificar la misma tabla

Comment: me creo el atributo usuarios pero fue solo momentáneo, no quedo el atributo  permanente. Y ademas el nombre y apellido quedaron juntos.

Comment: Okay, solo le falta un " " en medio de nombre y apellido. Lo modifico ahora

Comment: UPDATE responsables SET usuarios=CONCAT(nombre," ", apellido) FROM responsables; me marca error #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM responsables' en la linea 1(no entiendo en el FROM se supone que se ingresa el nombre de la tabla que se desea modificar)

Comment: Le quite el ```FROM``` ya que era parte de la consulta anterior y se me olvido quitarlo. Lo siento

Comment: ahora me aparece esto: #1054 - La columna 'usuarios' en field list es desconocida                                                                                              
(tengo entendido que usuarios seria el nombre del nuevo atributo(que seria la unión de los atributos nombre y apellido))

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me ahorraste muchísimo trabajo :D